# How to clone an SD card for use with smaller SD cards?

Tags: sd-card, clone, disk-image

I have an SD card of 16gb that I want to clone and have to send to another individual with a 16gb card. There's a problem however where my brand of card must be slightly larger than his by a few mb because his computer won't let him write the .img file to his sd card for size reasons.

I' tried several guides:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450844/disk-image-without-free-space
https://dustymabe.com/2012/11/15/create-a-disk-image-without-enough-free-space/

and a couple others with modified versions of a dd script. There was one guide that mentioned using a tool called truncate to short the image after it has been cloned but couldn't find that utility.

All no luck as the resulting image is still the same 16gb.

Would any of you have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: `truncate` is available for me on Cygwin. What distribution are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04.3,

Comment: Ubuntu should already have truncate as it's a part of the `coreutils` package. Did you try running `truncate` from the Terminal?